# Firebase/GCM notification returns empty message_id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been implementing a GCM/FCM solution for web notifications.

I recently started getting this return message:

```
{
    "multicast_id":8525.....,
    "success":1,
    "failure":0,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":[{"message_id":""}]
    }
```

Which on the one hand indicates `success`, but there is no `message_id` value, and indeed, the notification is not received at the recipient's end.

What could cause this?

UPDATE: Looks like the scenario is sending the *identical* message to 2 message recipients (ie, exact same parameters, except for the TO token), and the 2nd one is not being sent. Is there any reason why this should be the case?

Thanks